# AWS Ubuntu via Putty

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, putty

I´m having some problems while trying to connect with my Ubuntu server via Putty.

I´m following this instructions:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html
```

And I´m getting the following error:

```
"Connection timed out"
```

I generated my private key with "puttyGen" and I´m using host name like

```
ubuntu@ec2-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

AMI is configured with the same ".pem" that I used in puttyGen.

Thank you! =)

Comment: If you're getting a connection timeout error, your issue is almost assuredly network-based. You'll have to resolve that before you can worry about your SSH keys.

Comment: But I´m not having problems with my connection actually. My internet is working fine. Seems like there is something blocking...

Comment: Yes, if something is blocking you, that would still be a network-related issue.

Answer (score -1):

"Connection timed out" Indicates that (probably) a TCP connection could not be established. One of the following is likely the cause:

1. EC2 Security group is not configured to allow incoming access on port 22.
2. Software firewall on the client host preventing outgoing connection on port 22 to EC2
3. Network firewall at client site preventing outgoing connection on port 22 to EC2
4. A problem with the Ubuntu image - sshd may not be running.